# How to generate species presence/absence matrix from lat/long data using R

Tags: r

I have a long list of multiple species with lat/long data.

[image: Sample Data]

I want to generate presence-absence matrix (1,0) for all the species using the lat/long data. However, there is a case where multiple species occurred in the same lat/long (site). How can I consider this in R and produce the sample data frame below.

[image: Desired matrix]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy enough to do with **tidyverse**. First some example data:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  Sp = c('SP1', 'SP1', 'SP2', 'SP2', 'SP2'),
  Long = c(118, 119, 118, 119, 119),
  Lat = c(10, 11, 10, 11, 12)
)

  Sp     Long   Lat
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 SP1     118    10
2 SP1     119    11
3 SP2     118    10
4 SP2     119    11
5 SP2     119    12
```

And then a pivot operation. `spread` has recently been superseded by `pivot_wider` in **tidyr** (though `spread` will still be supported for now).

```
df2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(present = 1) %>% # create a dummy column
  pivot_wider(names_from = Sp, values_from = present) %>% # turn 'Sp' column into 'SP1' and 'SP2'
  mutate_at(vars(SP1, SP2), ~ifelse(is.na(.), 0, 1)) # fill in missing columns with 0

   Long   Lat   SP1   SP2
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1   118    10     1     1
2   119    11     1     1
3   119    12     0     1
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a new variable for location, concatenating lat lon:

```
table <- table%>%mutate(location = paste(long,lat,sep="/"))
```

Then spread the table

```
table <- table%>%spread(Sp,location)
```

Then make it dummy

```
table[,3:4] <- ifelse(is.na(table[,3:4]),0,1)
```

Make sure to change the numbers `3:4` according to the amount of columns that you will have.